# Twilio Connect in Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, twilio

I would like to add twilio connect button to my salesforce app, 
The issue I am facing is what to do with the AUTHORIZE URL, As I need it to return ( after authorization)back to user salesforce.

Any solution ?

Comment: What did you try so far?